# HTMLUNIT Driver : The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available

Tags: selenium, playframework-2.0, htmlunit

I have a problem with Scala fluentlenium tests on play 2.1.1 and HTMLUNIT driver.

The error is the next :

`[error] 2013-04-13 15:15:40,548 - c.g.h.j.StrictErrorReporter - runtimeError: message=[The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available.] sourceName=[http://localhost:3333/assets/libs/jquery-1.9.1.js] line=[928] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]`

It's the same with jquery 1.7.1.
The tests with FIREFOX driver (firefox 20 on computer) are OK, with the version dependency of fluentlenium-festassert 0.7.8

I think it's due to the default browser version of HTMLUNIT, but i don't arrive to change this version.

Thank for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. You need to do 2 things. Change the code - the samples dont seem to work, but also you do need to install the selenium driver otherwise it doesnt install the plugin for the web browser. To do that add this to your build config:

```
      "org.seleniumhq.selenium" % "selenium-java" % "2.31.0"
```

As per this discussion here: [https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/play-framework/browser$20tests/play-framework/AlJwpRfyXv0/Ry8Jsxj8mCcJ](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/play-framework/browser%2420tests/play-framework/AlJwpRfyXv0/Ry8Jsxj8mCcJ)

Then, some code like this will work:

```
package Selenium

import org.specs2.mutable._
import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._


class SeleniumTest extends Specification {

  val app = FakeApplication()
  "Application" should {


    "works from within a browser" in new WithBrowser(webDriver = Helpers.FIREFOX, app = app) {

      running(FakeApplication()) {
        browser.goTo("/")
        //browser.$("#title").getTexts().get(0) must equalTo("Welcome")
        browser.waitUntil[Boolean]{
          browser.pageSource contains ("Welcome")
        }


        //info(browser.$("#title").toString)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Its pretty sad that this isn't documented better.